# How would I get a JUnit class in my programme to provide String input to the console following a prompt?

Tags: java, junit, io

I have a programme with a `main()` method that, at TWO different times in the run, asks the user for a line of input. It then takes those two lines of input and compares them in a particular way.

I have a JUnit test class that initialises 6 Strings (`string1, string2,...,string6`) and I can't figure out how to take those Strings and simulate user input by sending them to `System.in` when the programme prompts the user to do so.

Essentially, on the first run of the programme, the programme will say, "Please enter your first string," and then later will say, "Please enter your second string." At those two prompts, I want to input `string1` and `string2` respectively from my test class. Then, on the second run of the programme, I want to input `string3` and `string4`

Is there a way to do this? I tried making this as comprehensible as I could, but I understand if I'm struggling to get my point across. Let me know if there's anything you don't understand and I will do my best to clarify any of the foggy details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refactor your code and separate the part which performs the calculations from the part that takes input from the console. Then you can very easily write the test for the part that performs the calculations, by passing the necessary input as parameters. The part that works with the console is typically very straightforward and does not require testing.

Testing this without refactoring the code is fairly involved. You'll need to replace System.in and System.out with pairs of PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream. Then you'll need to start a thread that will read data from the PipedInputStream connected to System.out and, as it sees the input prompt, write the expected input to the PipedOutputStream connected to System.in.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do this. I could give you a long answer, but the essence of it is that I'm not allowed to at this point.

Comment: Edited my answer to describe an outline of how this can be tested without refactoring the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TextFromStandardInputStream](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/#TextFromStandardInputStream) rule of the library [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/).

```
public class YourTest {
  @Rule
  public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock
    = emptyStandardInputStream();

  @Test
  public void test() {
    systemInMock.provideText("first string\nsecond string");
    YourApp.main()
    ...
  }
}
```